# Specifying multiple filter criteria through Oozie command line

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to to search for some specific oozie jobs through command line.
I am using the following syntax for the same 
`$ oozie jobs -filter status=RUNNING ;status=KILLED`

However the command only returns jobs which are RUNNING and not the KILLED jobs.Need assistance in figuring out why the multiple criteria is not working ( I am expecting the results for RUNNING and KILLED jobs to be ORed as mentioned in the [official oozie documentation](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/oozie/DG_CommandLineTool.html))

Am I missing something obvious here? Please suggest

*Version : Oozie client build version: 2.3.2-cdh3u5*

Answer (score 13):

You have to escape the semicolon, since it's being interpreted before reaching oozie. Run the command like this:

```
$ oozie jobs -filter status=RUNNING\;status=KILLED
```

Comment: Also quoting the string: `$ oozie jobs -filter "status=RUNNING;status=KILLED"`

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the string as @tokland mentioned worked for me, escaping didn't.

```
$ oozie jobs -jobtype bundle -filter "status=RUNNING;status=RUNNINGWITHERROR;user=myuser"
```