# oozie filter jobs using "not equal" condition

Tags: filter, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am using Oozie coordinators and the web console for tracking them. In order to find my job I usually use a filter

user=XXX;status=running

I know that this is also valid for the command line "-filter " (see [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html))

However in some cases I would like to use the condition status(not equal)killed

Is this possible? what is the corresponding syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

am not aware of such kind of operation {not equals} function is defined in any of the supported Oozie.
Instaed of Not Equal KILLED... you can try EQUAL RUNNING/SUSPEND/COMPLETE/PREP ... as both will give the same ans :)

Comment: Is there an OR operator? I tried "status=running/killed" but it didn't work

Comment: no there is only single option status=<option> at a single time.

Comment: You can do multiple statuses if you separate them with an escaped semi-colon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364567/specifying-multiple-filter-criteria-through-oozie-command-line   

`oozie jobs -jobtype coordinator  -filter status=KILLED\;status=RUNNING`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, there's no Not-Equals operator.

I am using 
`user=XXX;status=RUNNING;status=RUNNINGWITHERROR;status=PREP`